# Is the SlicePitch value wrong?

Tags: c#, textures, directx-11, sharpdx, direct3d11

I have been trying to copy the contents from a Texture2DArray using `Device.ImmediateContext.Mapsubresource()`. I have done this multiple times on my old laptop and it worked fine, but when I did it using Intel Iris Xe Graphics for some reason there are gaps of zeros in the middle.

This is a sample code for it:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint count);

public static unsafe float[] GetData()
{
    int gpuAdapterIndex = 0;

    SharpDX.DXGI.Adapter1 gpu;
    using (var factory = new SharpDX.DXGI.Factory1())
    {
        gpu = factory.GetAdapter1(gpuAdapterIndex);
    }

    Device device = new Device(gpu, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug);

    int pixelSize = sizeof(float);
    int width = 10;
    int height = 19;
    int depth = 3;
    float[] data = new float[width * height * depth];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = i;  
    }

    DataRectangle[] rectangles = new DataRectangle[depth];

    fixed (float* dataPtr = data)
    {
        IntPtr p = (IntPtr)dataPtr;

        for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.Length; i++)
        {
            rectangles[i] = new DataRectangle(IntPtr.Add(p, width * height * pixelSize * i), width * pixelSize);
        }
    }

    Texture2D t = new Texture2D(device, new Texture2DDescription()
    {
        ArraySize = depth,
        CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Write | CpuAccessFlags.Read,
        BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
        Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R32_Float,
        Height = height,
        Width = width,
        MipLevels = 1,
        Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging,
        SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
        OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
    }, rectangles);

    float[] output = new float[data.Length];

    DataBox box = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(t, 0, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None);

    fixed (float* o = output)
    {
        IntPtr dst = (IntPtr)o;
        IntPtr scr = box.DataPointer;

        for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                CopyMemory(dst, scr, (uint)(width * pixelSize));

                scr = IntPtr.Add(scr, box.RowPitch);
                dst = IntPtr.Add(dst, width * pixelSize);
            }
        }
    }

    device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(t, 0);

    t.Dispose();
    device.Dispose();

    return output;
}
```

When I check `box.SlicePitch` and compare it to the actual size of each slice, they were different which, if I am not wrong, is not supposed to happen.

```
(width,height), box.rowpitch, box.slicepitch, real slice pitch
(2, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(3, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(4, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(5, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(6, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(7, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(8, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(9, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(10, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(11, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(12, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(13, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(14, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(15, 38), 64, 2432, 2560
(17, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(18, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(19, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(20, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(21, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(22, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(23, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(24, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(25, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(26, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(27, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(28, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(29, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(30, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(31, 38), 128, 4864, 5120
(33, 38), 192, 7296, 7680
(34, 38), 192, 7296, 7680
(35, 38), 192, 7296, 7680
(36, 38), 192, 7296, 7680
(37, 38), 192, 7296, 7680
(38, 38), 192, 7296, 7680
(39, 38), 192, 7296, 7680
(40, 38), 192, 7296, 7680
```

This does not happen with any other graphics card I have (Intel graphics HD 520 and nvidia mx450).
It appears that what is happening is that instead of calculating the slice pitch to be `height * box.RowPitch` it rounds the height to the nearest multiple of 4 above it and then multiply it by `box.RowPitch`. My biggest concern is can this happen in other cases? If so then is there is a general way to deal with them?

Answer (score 0):

> can this happen in other cases?

yes, pitch size can be adjusted in favor of memory alignment or compression, D3D11 does not enforce that every hardware does it the same way, and also this concept is not limited to DirectX; your current graphics card didn't do anything wrong, it simply opted for alignment.

> is there a general way to deal with them?

just do not assume that every subresource or their row & depth are placed consistently right next to each other in memory. you should handle each block of memory (in your case, each row) separately.

Comment: Thanks. When you said "you should handle each block of memory" how can I do that?

Comment: What I mean was, when incrementing the pointer value, you should increase by the real RowPitch / SlicePitch value you've acquired through `MapSubresource`. I re-read your code and saw that you are already incrementing `src` by `box.RowPitch` inside the `height` loop, but `src` is not guaranteed to be at the next slice after this loop ends. You should re-calculate `src` (the beginning of the slice) in each `depth` loop using `box.SlicePitch`.  `IntPtr src = IntPtr.Add(box.DataPointer, box.SlicePitch * z);`

Comment: But this is the real problem, which is that the value in `box.SlicePitch` is incorrect so whenever I recalculate `src` the value would be incorrect. I want to know if there is a method to get the correct slice pitch, because the current method I used to determine the slice pitchs in above is slow and tedious.

Comment: Wait, you mean the pitch value you got from `MapSubresource` is wrong? I misunderstood earlier. In that case there is indeed some problem here.

Comment: I checked the official API doc and there isn't any other function to determine the pitch value. But there is an alternative for reading sub resource data, a function called `ReadFromSubresource` from `ID3D11Device3`. You can see if that function bypasses this problem. (use `QueryInterface` to cast Device to Device3)